# Central air compressor fan reflects sunlight into house. What can I do about it?

Tags: central-air

I have a new construction and for whatever reason the HVAC installers placed the compressor right in front of a bedroom window.  I don't have any complaints about the noise (it is actually pretty quiet).  Unfortunately, the fan blades reflect sunlight and it produces this annoying strobing effect within the room.

My builder was thinking about spray painting a black matte on the blade, but I'm wondering if there is something more "professional" that they can do to reduce or eliminate the reflection.

Comment: Before reading the rest of your post, I was going to suggest the painting of the reflective surfaces..

Comment: painting it would be best. Otherwise curtains work great for this.

Comment: Removing the grill and painting matte black is about as professional as you can get unless you move the unit. We had to do similar on a fan in a non-negotiable location. For some of us, the strobing is worse than annoying, visual epilepsy events aren't fun.

Comment: Paint, plants, or some sort of shield that blocks sun from the problem direction without blocking airflow. Painting should handled or at least specifically approved **by the HVAC installer/contractor**, not some random painter or the GC acting on their own, to make sure it does not screw up the unit or your warranty on the unit. You don't want paint getting on the cooling coils, and you don't want the fan to be unbalanced by the paint.

Answer (score -2):

------------Edit -----------

Another idea which may be applicable , and avoid performing a paint , is using a piece of 3M membrane like this

http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_EU/3MGraphics/GraphicSolutions/Products/Catalogue/?N=5799&rt=c3

---

------initial answer---------

I think that it is not appropriate to paint a brand new piece of equipment , painted with electrostatic paint and perfectly finished, for both the aesthetic part and for potential warranty issues.
If I had this problem I would order from a blacksmith a small shelter skeleton and I would put a polycarbonate sheet as a roof (this can be done by a carpenter as well without the need a the polycarbonate sheet).
To get a better idea here is a picture of the concept :
[image]

You will of course use  a much smaller size to cover only the unit.

Comment: I don't know what part of the world this will be acceptable.  But where I live (US) this will never pass code.

Comment: I am not going to argue about to which part of the world this will be acceptable. I think though that (in case you live in your own house and not in a complex or apartment) this "hat" I am suggesting is like a tiny awning and I admit I do not no if there is legislation in the US about awnings. I hope I offered some help.